# ¿Porque esta relación no funciona?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller, model, relaciones

Me tiene loco este caso, yo quiero traer la información de una tabla llamada student_schedules con todo y sus relaciones, pero hay una de las relaciones que no me trae la información correspondiente, la relación tiene el nombre de studentSchedules y la traigo en el controlador de esta forma:

```
$query = StudentSchedule::query()->with('studentSchedules','user', 'instructor', 'course', 'location');
```

La relación desde el modelo es esta establecida de esta forma:

```
public  function studentSchedules(){
    return $this->hasMany(StudentSchedulesApproved::class);
}
```

Y la migración desde la tabla de StudentSchedulesApproved es de esta manera:

```
Schema::create('student_schedules_approveds', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('student_schedules_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('calification')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('approved');
        //relations
        $table->foreign('student_schedules_id')->references('id')
            ->on('student_schedules');
});
```

Lo que quiero saber es como atraves de la relación me traiga la informacion de esta tabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema puede radicar en que no indicas la llave foreanea, la cual no tiene el formato estandar para laravel

Ej:

```
return $this->hasMany(StudentSchedulesApproved::class,'student_schedules_id','id');
```